Any mobile browsers with mouse-over, mouse-hover support? to use web apps with drag-n-drop on large display?
I'm using some web apps on large display with a physical mouse. Everything works fine, except some features are about drag-n-drop, and without the mouse-over, hover, states they won't work.
Any modern mobile browsers with hover state of web contents?
Similar question (12y ago): web browser / plugin with mouse hover mode

An a Samsung tablet on Android 14 with S-Pen I experienced some sort of "mouse-over" in Chrome. Even with switched of S-Pen e.g. the tabs in Chrome show a preview image when the S-Pen hovers over it and links change color. Not sure if this would also work wouth a mouse. The effect is also present in Firefox.

that samsung tablet is so nice

Hi, please note that asking for app recommendation explicitly is off-topic now (the linked question might predate current policy, and while the title is off-topic, the question body at least asks how-to in general; I'll edit the title to conform with current policy). It's better to state what problem you want to solve without restricting to app solutions (looks like the title can be reworded to "How to do drag and drop using mouse on web browsers?", but the question body might need some rework). Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [softwarerecs.se].
